# jquery move the second navi by animation and position absolute

Tags: javascript, jquery

i will show the second Navi over jquery animation an position absolute - like this demo:

```js
$('ul.level0 li').hover(function() {
  var cat = '#new-' + this.id;
  $(cat).animate({'left': '+100px'},'slow');
}, function() {
  var cat = '#new-' + this.id;
  $(cat).animate({'left': '-100px'},'slow');
});
```

```css
.alles-zwei {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:1;
}

ul.level0 {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:2;
  background:#fff;
  width:100px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="level0">
<li class="level1" id="cat2441">Text</li>
<li class="level1" id="cat2450">Text</li>
<li class="level1" id="cat2455">Text</li>
</ul>

<div class="alles-zwei" id="new-cat2441">
  <ul class="level1">
    <li class="level2">Text</li>
    <li class="level3">Text</li>
    <li class="level2">Text</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="alles-zwei" id="new-cat2450">
  <ul class="level1">
    <li class="level2">Text</li>
    <li class="level3">Text</li>
    <li class="level2">Text</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="alles-zwei" id="new-cat2455">
  <ul class="level1">
    <li class="level2">Text</li>
    <li class="level3">Text</li>
    <li class="level2">Text</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

But when i move to the second navi - the second navi disappears - there is no possibility to get there - how can I do this best?

Comment: Your question is not clear or might I am not getting you. You mention, second navi disappears. But I can see it is present in this snippet and my created demo as well. What is the exact issue ?

Comment: ok sorry - i cant click on the second navi (ul.level1)